# JQuery : selector chain with attribute filter : result does not persist?

Tags: jquery, attributes, css-selectors, chaining

I am pulling my hair out!! grrr...

This *seems* to work:

```
//get all the foo and bar links that point to a named anchor:
$("a.foo,a.bar").filter("[href^=#]").click
(
    function()
    {
        doSomething( $(this).attr("href").substr(1) );
        return false;
    }
);
```

When I log the output of '$(this).attr("href").substr(1)' to the console I see the anchorname without the hash, for all the relevant links. All good. But inside doSomething(), typeof() of says I have a string - but it's empty!! Why?!!

```
function doSomething(str)
{
    //log str : it's empty!!
}
```

Usually soon after I post a question on here it's too bizarre for anyone to help me or I figure out my own stupidity later. I hope someone can help this time! :-(

============== **SOLVED** =====================

********* It was my own stupidity **********

inside doSomething the first thing that my code did was:

```
if(str = "") return;
```

(slaps forehead). Thank you all for making me stare at this in a different way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I can't reproduce this.](http://jsbin.com/uxawu) Sounds like an issue with the `doSomething` code itself - do a quick code review to make sure you're pointing to the right function and that you're not modifying the argument before use.

Comment: omg... thank you about the comment about 'modifying the argument'...
I feel so stupid. I had done 'if(str = "") return; can you spot the problem? Yah...

Answer (score 0):

note: This isn't the correct answer! But I'm going to leave it here in case it is of use to other Sizzle users.

---

It's a bug in Sizzle (the selector library used by jQuery).

The problem is when you access `link.href` in JavaScript you don't get the text of the `href` attribute, you get the resolved absolute URL. Naturally this begins with `http://` and not `#`.

When you call `link.attr('href')` jQuery detects the special case and applies a workaround. When you use a selector, Sizzle doesn't. It tries:

```
attrHandle: {
    href: function(elem){
        return elem.getAttribute("href");
    }
},
```

but this workaround doesn't work on IE up to version 7, as they make `getAttribute` equal to just getting the JavaScript property. [The correct workaround would be to use `getAttributeNode` instead, or sniff IE and use the proprietary `getAttribute('href', 2)` extension.]

So the selector engine gets `http://...` for the href attribute and of course this never matches `^=#`.

If you do it yourself with a filter function it should work:

```
$('a.foo, a.bar').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('href').substring(0, 1)==='#';
})...
```

Comment: Ah... looks like it's OK in this case. Sizzle does have this bug, but current versions of jQuery monkey-patch the offending function to fix it! [Line 2196 of jQuery 1.3.2.]

Answer (score -2):

try `substr(0)` first character is at index 0 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Comment: I think he's intentionally trying to omit the #.

Comment: ...what does that mean? xD Input is always appreciated, but to appreciate input and say it's wrong are not mutually exclusive.